# Sharing image taking too much time to go to facebook application

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-sharing

I'm trying to share an image on facebook (the device screenshot) but it's taking too long to redirect to facebook application and I don't know why. Sometimes it takes up to 30/40 seconds.

I would like to know if this is a normal behavior or if the problem could be in my code... If it is normal, how could I show a progress dialog showing that something is going on?

Here is the important part of my code:

```
public void goToFacebookToSharePhoto(Bitmap image) {
    if(image != null && ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(image)
                .build();
        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();
        shareDialog.show(content);
    } else {
        //show dialog error
    }
}
```

This method is called when the share button is clicked.

Comment: try to resize your bitmap and memory size of the image your are uploading.

Comment: hey i have still this problem you have any solution  or its Facebook side issue??  i have not bitmap  only image URL and title